# Calling application context from init-method

Tags: spring

I have a standard 'context-holder' bean (lets say MyContext) implementing the `ApplicationContextAware` in my spring configuration file and another bean defined with init-method.

Within the init-method I call `MyContext.getApplicationContext().get("something")` but I get `NullPointerException` since the application context is not set (yet). The bean is an integration test.

I suppose the problem is that I define the `MyContext` bean after the bean with the init-method. Is that right? I think the Spring should be smart enough to set the context first.

Is there any solution for situations like this? I mean, when you have defined the `ApplicationContextAware` bean after any other beans with init-method calling the application context itself?

What is the Spring's flow by the way? I would accept an answer like 'The spring loads all configurations first, then creates all bean instances, satisfy all dependencies, call all init-methods and finally it sets the application context to the `ApplicationContextAware` bean - so you cant use the application context in init-methods'.

Comment: Can you post a sample code?

Comment: You shouldn't be working with the `ApplicationContext` you should be using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @PostConstruct. Method with this annotation will be called immediately after constriction of bean but before it is used anywhere.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void afterInitMethod() throws Exception {
     //do you things there
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring provides a way to tell the container that a bean depends on another bean and hence should be instantiated after it. Once you specify the dependency, it wouldn't matter in what order you list the `bean` definitions in your `spring.xml` file.

```
<bean id="dependentBean" class="com.my.app.DependentBean" depends-on="appContext" />

<bean id="appContext" class="com.my.app.MyContext" />
```